# Why can't I run any update query in access 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007

When I try to run any update query in Access 2007, I get the message

> that action blocked because an available ....

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Update data by using a query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/ha100765271033.aspx#3) and go to

**Stop Disabled Mode from blocking a query**

> By default, Access disables all action
>   queries (update, append, delete, or
>   make table queries) unless your
>   database is in a trusted location or
>   the database is signed and trusted. If
>   you have not taken either of these
>   actions, you can still enable the
>   query for the current database session
>   by clicking Enable Content on the
>   Message Bar.
>
> If you try to run an action query and
>   it seems like nothing occurs, check
>   the Access status bar for the
>   following message:
>
> **This action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode.**

Also [Stop disabled mode from blocking a query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102564031033.aspx)

Comment: above links are broken